# Does Demosthenes' Hierarchy of Foreignness have a real world root?

Tags: enders-game, speaker-for-the-dead

In the second Enders Game book *Speaker for the Dead* the concept of the Hierarchy of Foreignness is described:

- **Utlanning** are individuals who are of the same species as the subject, and are from a different region, city, or country.
- **Framlings** are individuals who are recognized as being of the same species as the subject, but who are from another planet.
- A **raman** is an individual recognized as a sentient being who is of another species, but with whom communication is possible. In Speaker for the Dead and Xenocide, the Piggies and the Buggers are identified as raman.
- The **varelse** are true aliens: they are sentient beings, but are so foreign that no meaningful communication is possible with the subject.
- **Djur** are non-sentient beings. They are capable of independent thought and action, but their mode of communication cannot relay any meaningful information to the subject because the djur itself lacks the capacity for rational thought and self-awareness.

It's an interesting characterization of species. Does this classification have any real world origin? Is it simply a literary mechanism used by Orson Scott Card to stratify his universe?

Comment: This should [also] be asked on Philosophy.SE (perhaps reworded version to fit them better). if you do, post a link here in a comment.

Comment: Out of curiosity -- and I don't remember this from the books -- how do you tell varelse from djur? If no meaningful communication is possible, how can you tell if a living being is sentient or self-aware?

Comment: The thrust of the argument is that you can't tell the diffence all the time. Obviously, if a species has gained the technology to travel through space, such as the virus-builders (I haven't read beyond *Children of the Mind*, so apologies if they have a nae beyond that) then you must be sentient, even though you may be too alien to communicate with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are real-world roots for these terms. They are all of Scandinavian - specifically Swedish - origin. The Enderverse Wiki mentions this, for example [here](http://ansible.wikia.com/wiki/Utl%C3%A4nning). While Card has never outright stated he based those words on their Swedish antecedents, the fact that the planet Demosthenes was on at the time was full of Scandinavians seems to directly imply such.

Comment: The Swedish words do not, however, have the connotations that Card uses.

Answer (score 3):

Card actually states that the language originates from Swedish. This can be found in the author's definitive edition of *Speaker for the Dead*. In the novel, the first description of the terms states that they come from Nordic: "The Nordic language recognizes four orders of foreignness" (Card 34). Furthermore, before the prologue, the book's section "Pronouncing Foreign Names" states that "the Nordic spoken in Trondheim evolved from Swedish" (Card xxvii).

In the "real world," Nordic language refers to North Germanic Languages, which include Swedish, Danish, and Norwegian.

Work Cited:
Card, Orson Scott. *Speaker for the Dead*. New York: Tom Doherty Associates, 1994. Print.

Comment: Do you have a link to the cited work?